# python mongoengine keys of document

Tags: python, mongoengine

I start to use mongoengine in Python as a Document-Object Mappe on an already established collection. The documents are schema less. Now for development, debugging and might within the application the question what fields/keys the object `User` has is of interest.

Is there a different approach to achieve the same, may be without querying the document every time?

```
class User(DynamicDocument):
    field_one = StringField()

    def keys(self):
        return type(self).objects.as_pymongo().filter(id=self.id).first().keys()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `instance._data.keys()` for this, it will combine both known and dynamic fields.

```
from mongoengine import *
connect()

class TestDoc(DynamicDocument):
    f1 = StringField()

# simulate document with dynamic fields
td1 = TestDoc(f1='garbage1')
td1.other_field = 'garbage2'
td1.other_field2 = 'garbage99'
td1.save()

# show how it looks in the database
print(TestDoc.objects.as_pymongo())    # [{'_id': ObjectId('...'), 'f1': 'garbage1', 'other_field': 'garbage2', 'other_field2': 'garbage99'}]

doc = TestDoc.objects.first()
print(doc._data.keys())    # ['f1', 'id', 'other_field', 'other_field2']
```

You can also look at `instance._dynamic_fields.keys()` which will list only the dynamic ones.